# How to pass string iterator variable to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, string, function, iterator

The following code just prints a string obtained from the main function using another function called recurse. I just wanted to know how I can pass a string iterator variable to another function. But the code I wrote doesn't print any result. Can someone tell me what is the error and what I can do to make the code work ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void recurse(string::iterator &start, string::iterator &end)
{
    while(start != end)
    {
        cout << *start;
        ++start;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    string::iterator i = s.begin(), j = s.end();

    cout << "Enter the string here: ";
    getline(cin, s);

    recurse(i, j);

}
```

Comment: By `getline` your iterators are invalidated. You should call `begin`/`end` after string was entered. Also don't pass iterators by reference, they are lightweight object, pass by values. The following `recurse(s.begin(), s.end());` is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During initialization, `i and j` points to invalid address(as `s` is empty). But when you took the input then it s gets a new string and `i and j` are pointing to the old address (**invalid**).

So declare iteration after taking input.

```
string s;

cout << "Enter the string here: ";
getline(cin, s);
string::iterator i = s.begin(), j = s.end();

recurse(i, j);
```

Comment: Oh! @rafix07 already answered this in the comment section.
This is same thing I wanted to say.